# Cannot enter "Umlaute" on php console

Tags: php, console, encoding

I do have a problem with german "umlaute" on the console. Whereas I have no problem entering them on the bash console, it is a problem on the php console

[image: Console issues with umlauts]

PHP is all set to UTF-8

```
iconv.input_encoding => UTF-8 => UTF-8
iconv.internal_encoding => UTF-8 => UTF-8
iconv.output_encoding => UTF-8 => UTF-8
HTTP input encoding translation => disabled
mbstring.encoding_translation => Off => Off
mbstring.internal_encoding => no value => no value
default_charset => utf-8 => utf-8
```

also is the console

```
vagrant@worker:~$ env | grep LC_ALL
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```

I am currently stuck where to search for the issue. I am inside a vagrant machine logged in via `vagrant ssh` if that of any concern. What is wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in PHP.

Comment: on my mac it works just fine, the version I am using in vagrant is 5.3.10, but on mac it is 5.4.26, I will update to the same version and have another trial

Comment: mh I do not mind being downvoted, but some kind of hint why or if some information are missing would be actually helpful